# How to create a global date entry shortcut/hotkey?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Excel and Google Sheets both allow you to enter the current date (and time) with a single keystroke.  I would love to be able to do this in other applications too but can't find any way to do this without resorting to 3rd party apps that also do a whole lot more that I don't need.

Using Automator/Services won't work because the main application I want to use this with is a Java app called Tradewonk, and services appear to not be available to a java application (there is no "Services" option in the "Java" menu that appears when the app is running).

So any other suggestions for how I can generate the current date/time with a keystroke?  I'm on macOS Sierra.

Comment: My first thought is to still try using Automator to run an AppleScript and to then add a keyboard shortcut to run it. Is this something you've already tried? If so, then I won't formulate it into an answer. But if you haven't, I can add an answer and then we'll find out if it works with Tradewonk?

Comment: I thought this required the use of a service to execute the Applescript?  No services are available to the Java app.  If I'm wrong and a service isn't required, then I can give it a shot.

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure to be honest. I've set up a number of Services with keyboard shortcuts, and they run even when the Services aren't displayed in the Services menu, but I'm not sure how this will or won't work in the context of a Java app with no Services at all. As an aside, can you do a normal 'paste' from the clipboard into the Tradewonk app?

Comment: Yep a normal paste works fine.  I've wound up finding a solution though which I've just posted as an answer.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Haha, that's great! Glad you got it sorted. BetterTouchTool is certainly one of those fantastic utilities! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll be damned... I had a solution the whole time.  I use BetterTouchTool for various gestures on my trackpad, but had forgotten that it could trigger text sequences as well, including current date/time.  Mapped them to shortcuts and voila, works great even in a Java app!  Admittedly it uses a 3rd party app but it's one I was already using (and woefully underutilizing its features, clearly!)